# Get APNS Background callback with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios10

I'm trying to get a callback when Firebase Cloud Message sends out a push notification to the device is in background state.  I get both background + foreground banners but

```
userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

is being called only in foreground.

I'm reading the docs and it doesn't seem to be a way to specify "content-available : 1" with FCM payload.  Everything in the doc acknowledges that the callbacks will not work while in background state.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

Basically, I need a way to fetch new data and update UI when app is in the background.  Would appreciate any tips or workaround ideas.